# comet style application with loops

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, jquery, sql

Do all comet style applications require a loop somewhere in the application on the serverside to detect updates/changes?  If no, please could you explain how the logic behind a loopless comet style application would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of application will always require a loop, you need to periodically check for new data etc. Of course you can make the "loop" non-blocking by using an even-loop based approach, but in the end there's still a loop somewhere.

Just think about it for a moment, how would you make it work without a loop? I sure can't imagine a way that doesn't utilize a loop *somewhere*.

Comment: So basically, google wave, with there key word level collaboration system where looping checking for each key press difference in their database???

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "looping in their database". Of course, if you want to have real-time collaboration you need to check for every keypress that a user sends and then send them out to the other users, their might be some caching in play to reduce the number of database writes though, but you still need to check the comet connections for new incoming data, which will require a loop (be it blocking or not).

Comment: Is it not possible to get the server to wait for a keypress, and as soon as it receives a keypress from user1, it sends that keypress to user2,2,3,4,n then save that keypress in the database?

Comment: instead of looping to check for differences in the database?

Comment: Well how would you wait for a keypress? *Something* needs to check whether the socket (or wherever the data comes from) has new data. If you wait you do blocking IO, basically you loop and check on each iteration of there's new data available. And event based approach may hide the looping from your application but it's still there, in some other thread outside of the scope of your "server".

Comment: ok, so it seems that looping is the only way to check for a change.  if I have 50,000 concurrent users, does that mean my server will be running 50,000 loops against my database server checking for changes until a change is found?

Comment: how does the apache event log work?  It more or less instantly records everything in terms of http requests.  Are they using loops too to constantly check for connections, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is, no, not all require a loop on the serverside.

Instead you can use long-polling AJAX calls from the browser to request data,

at which the server simply responds with the data and the browser waits until the response is gotten before sending a new request.

Comment: but how does the server wait? via looping?

Comment: It doesn't wait. It only responds continually.

Comment: But what if there is no change for 10 minutes, how does it know when a change happens?

Comment: That's the beauty of AJAX, the response tells the browser it's arrived.

Answer (score 1):

The solution could be stream_set_blocking. Use any possible blocking resource to be suspended by OS and wait for appropriate interruption.

Client side:

1. Ajax call to endpoint script (timeout for ajax e.g. 30 seconds - after 30 seconds initiate another one - after 30 seconds you will get response from server - script execution time reached)
2. If you will get response during 30 seconds handle response (async) and open new connection (as in comet done - I saw it in cometD client)

Server setup:

1. Setup apache timeouts (between request and data sent to 30-31 second), this is so apache will allow you to wait so much
2. set apache to allow lot of child instances (concurrent users * 1.5), but you need to be sure that you have enough memory for this amount of apache instances (+ memory used by php children)

Script one:

1. execution_time = 28
2. set shutdown_function in order to send response (timeout, but formatted and understandable for ajax if You need it)
3. you need to open file, empty one
4. enable blocking mode using stream_set_blocking for file stream
5. try read from file and you will get suspended until other process will write to file or timeout be reached.
6. As soon as script gets content in file written from other process it will get back and will send response. (this will trigger another ajax call and another slept process)

Worst thing is that you need to think how to get multiple reader scripts reading from same bus (file) without disturbing each other.
Also there could be that timeout will be exactly at that time when message will be written into bus.

(hope that this solution is not as bad as my English)